# how to apply filter method on this

Tags: javascript

> Now it's time to implement the filter function to convert a given array into one in which all elements are those which are multiples of 10. Given the array, input = [....], can you write a filter function on this array and reduce it to the one required? The input array has already been provided in the stub code. Store the output in a new array called "output" and print the resulting array.
>
> To verify your solution, you can look at the solution code of this question after submitting your code.

input is

```
var input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300]
```

I tried this:

```js
var input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300]
var output = [];
function outputthis(input){
    if(input % 10 == 0){
        console.log(input)
    }
}
outputthis(input);
```

Comment: And the problem/question is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You've missed a part of the task: _"Store the output in a new array called "output" and print the resulting array"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300];
    var output = [];
    output = input.filter( (x) => x % 10 === 0 );
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

`var input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300]; var output = input.filter( x => x % 10 === 0 ); console.log(output);`

```js
var input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300];
var output = input.filter( x => x % 10 === 0 );
console.log(output);
```

Comment: _What_ have changed? And _why_?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = [23,45,678,90,33,21,780,670,498,7493,58940,6565,900,370,1299,1300];
let output = input.filter( (x) => x % 10 === 0 );
console.log(output);
```